# Git/EGit doesn't seem to exist within eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

Hi I installed Egit from the eclipse market place...

[image]

[image]

...But when it doesn't appear in the Team drop down? I can't see it anywhere?

[image]

I've tried uninstalling and I received:

> "Java implementation of Git" cannot be fully uninstalled because other
>   installed software requires it.  The parts that are not required will
>   be uninstalled.
>
> "Eclipse Git Team Provider" cannot be fully uninstalled because other
>   installed software requires it.  The parts that are not required will
>   be uninstalled.

Any ideas?

**FYI**

- Eclipse Version: Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1)
- Mac OSx Yosemite
- Java 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple reinstall of eclipse was all that was needed. I hope this helps someone else.

[image]